# How to add bake times between different stages of pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am a beginner in writing server less application using aws-cdk. I need to add bake time between different stages of my pipeline. I have two test stages (beta, gamma) and production stage.
Didn't find anything useful on google. Please guide.

Comment: The simplest way would be to add a Manual Approval action - that way, you would have to manually approve the transition from one stage to the next. Would that work for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @eatsfood, I am glad that you guided me. I am actually a beginner in coding. I will take care of it next time.